# Access original frame in CefGlue when there is a popup

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefglue

I Use CEF and use ExecuteJavaScript to call Javascript functions and everything is fine but
when user click on something on the page that opens a new window, I lose my original frame.

Browser.IsPopup is true and Browser.GetFrameIdentifiers() and Browser.GetFrameNames() show all frames in the popup and not the main (original page).
even after closing popup (new window) there is no frame in the Browser.

PS: The original window is visible to the user when popup is open.

How can I access the original frame so I can still ExecuteJavaScript to that frame?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution.

By handling the BeforePopup and storing original frame.